# Easy way to make OpenCV's "undistort" run more efficiently?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, webcam

I'm currently in the works of making an auto-aiming turret, and my camera's have a noticeable fish eye effect, which is totally fine. I'm using OpenCV's `undistort()` function to handle this, with data from a camera checkerboard calibration.

I will most likely be running the vision system on a raspberry pi 4, and currently, my `undistort` function takes 80-90% of my CPU (i5-8600k OC 5GHz) when processing both of my cameras at 1280x720px, ideally this px as it's the largest and will provide best accuracy. Also note I'm aiming for a 15Hz update time.

Any ideas on how to make this more lightweight? Here's my code that I'm currently running as a test:

```
from cv2 import cv2
import numpy as np
import yaml
import time

cam1 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam2 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cam1.set(3, 1280)
cam1.set(4, 720)
cam2.set(3, 1280)
cam2.set(4, 720)

#load calibration matrix
with open ("calibration_matrix.yaml") as file:

    documents = yaml.full_load(file)
    x=0
    for item, doc in documents.items():
        if x == 0:
            mtx = np.matrix(doc)
            x = 1
        else:
            dist = np.matrix(doc)

def camera(ID, asd):
    if asd == -1:
        ID.release()

    ret, frame = ID.read()

    if ret:
        newcameramtx, roi = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx,dist,(w,h),1,(w,h))
        undistortedFrame = cv2.undistort(frame, mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx)
        undistortedFrame = undistortedFrame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        return undistortedFrame
while True:
    frame1 = camera(cam1, 0)
    frame2 = camera(cam2, 0)
    cv2.imshow('Frame 1', frame1)
    cv2.imshow('Frame 2', frame2)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        camera(cam1, -1)
        camera(cam2, -1)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: use initundistortrectifymap (once) and remap (for each image)

Comment: Will look into it. What's the difference between undistort?

Comment: I'm really stuck with implementing this function in python, I've read all there is to read that I can understand about the function. Can you provide an example in python?

Comment: sorry, only have C++ experience with that function. The idea is that the expensive part of undistort is performed only once and only the then precomputed pixel motion is performed for each image,

Comment: If your camera is fisheye, then you should be using `fisheye` module for calibration. [Example Code for Fisheye Calibration - Python](https://medium.com/@kennethjiang/calibrate-fisheye-lens-using-opencv-333b05afa0b0)

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll give the fish-eye a try. I was able to get the initUndistortRectifyMap work, and it runs many times lighter. I'll test out the fish eye method and compare performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments above resolved, here's the solution:

As @Micka said,

> use `initundistortrectifymap()` (once) and `remap()` (for each image)

`initundistortrectifymap()` basically takes the heavy load off of the undistort function (Micka) In practice, you run `initundistortrectifymap()` at the start of the program with the image calibration matrix and distance coefficients, and then `initundistortrectifymap()` returns two maps, map1 and map2.

These maps can be passed into the `remap()` function to remap your image, which is a significantly lighter function than `undistort()`. In my particular case, I have a fisheye camera, and OpenCV has fisheye modules that are optimized to undistort fish eye cameras with ease.